# Translating T-SQL script to a DB2 equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

**BACKGROUND**

We have a large routing table that we use to lookup people based on part number (PN).

Routing table:

| PN | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 51000 | Bob |
| 52000 | Bob |
| 61000 | John |
| 62000 | John |

A given PN will not match routing table exactly. We want it to find the closest solution possible.

Example: SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER = 51235 -> we want script to answer Bob.

Best solution we have found is to recursively search routing table with a loop until we get a hit.

Here is the T-SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
(
    PN INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
);

DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 5

WHILE (@Counter > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp_table
        SELECT * 
        FROM Routing
        WHERE LEFT(Routing.PN, @Counter) = LEFT([SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER], @Counter)
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temp_table)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
   
    SET @Counter = @Counter - 1
END

SELECT name, COUNT(name) count 
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count
```

**THE ISSUE**

Although this code works, it's in the wrong SQL language... DB2 is what this needs to be in. With a ton of effort we have been unable to convert this into something equivalent in DB2 unfortunately.

**THE REQUEST**

Convert script into a DB2 equivalent

Comment: I suggest https://github.com/dmtolpeko/sqlines

Comment: Will the PN's and search value always be 5 digit integers?

Comment: What should be returned on SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER = 56500? Bob? John? Nothing as with current algorithm? The same is for SPN = 0 or 999999.

Comment: @BartMcEndree - thanks for that. Ill try messing with it. On first glance it appears root cause might be I dont know how to work with DB2 language good enough to get a result like I can with MS SQL...

Comment: @Error_2646 - yes always 5 digits

Comment: @MarkBarinstein - Its not a perfect system for sure, but it does get us close enough to what we are wanting. Truthfully we are working with unreliable SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER  data so we cant achieve 100% anyway. 

56500 -> BOB (which works in script example). 

00000 or 99999 we are OK with returning null as a response if there isnt a match. This may point to a need for a routing table update.

Comment: What if you had (51000, Bob), (53000, John) and SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER = 52000?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein - There are possible gaps I do not deny that by any means. Just trying to get a new feature up and running. Its internal business related and already prone to errors given inaccuracy of SEARCH_PART_NUMBER. We were thinking this could get us close enough. But, I appreciate your comments pointing out possible gaps. Open to suggestions if you have a alternative method. We are by no means SQL experts.

Comment: I've provided the answer below, where the same logic you described is implemented in Db2. Yes, it's some strange approach of routing table construction and use, but only you can tell us, why you don't use, say, table of 3 columns instead: (pn_start, pn_end, name). Why, indeed?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent algorithm in Db2 with a single statement.
P - query parameters. 5 is a constant for your 5 digits only PNs.
You may play with different SEARCHED_PART_NUMBER (SPN) at the link below.

```
WITH 
  Routing (PN, Name) AS
  (
    VALUES 
      (51000, 'Bob ')
    , (52000, 'Bob ')
    , (61000, 'John')
    , (62000, 'John')
  )
, P (COUNTER, SPN) AS (VALUES (5, 51235))
, CTE (COUNTER) AS
  (
    SELECT COUNTER + 1
    FROM P
      UNION ALL
    SELECT T.COUNTER - 1
    FROM CTE T, P
    WHERE T.COUNTER > 1
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM Routing
      WHERE LEFT (Routing.PN, T.Counter - 1) = LEFT (P.SPN, T.Counter - 1)
    )
  )
SELECT Routing.Name, COUNT (Routing.Name) count
FROM Routing
CROSS JOIN P
JOIN 
(
  SELECT MIN (CTE.Counter) - 1 AS Counter
  FROM CTE
) T ON LEFT (Routing.PN, T.Counter) = LEFT (P.SPN, T.Counter)
WHERE T.Counter <> 0
GROUP BY Routing.Name
ORDER BY count
```

| NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IaSMDVWL)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a very different approach in both TSQL and DB2, both will be almost (if not exactly) the same:

```
CREATE TABLE routing (
    PN INTEGER,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Routing_PN ON routing (PN);
```

```
INSERT INTO routing (PN, Name) 
VALUES (51000, 'Bob'),
       (52000, 'Bob'),
       (61000, 'John'),
       (62000, 'John'),
       (1000,'overlap 1'),
       (1100,'overlap 1'),
       (1010,'overlap 2'),
       (1110,'overlap 2');
```

```
CREATE VIEW my_routing AS
SELECT PN
    , LEAD(PN, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY PN
        ) AS NextPN
    , Name
FROM routing;
```

```
SELECT
      name
    , pn
    , nextpn
FROM my_routing
WHERE 51235 between PN and NextPN
   OR 1050 between PN and NextPN
ORDER BY
      name
    , pn
    , nextpn
```

| NAME | PN | NEXTPN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 51000 | 52000 |
| overlap 1 | 1000 | 1100 |
| overlap 2 | 1010 | 1110 |

Amongst other things (like being simple SQL) this approach will locate any overlapping ranges (so you can do something about them).

[DB2 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cqTtuJew)

**nb** you could also store the wanted part numbers in a table structure e.g:

```
with example as (
    SELECT 51235 AS searchpn FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1050 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
    )
select 
    eg.searchpn, r.*
from example as eg
join my_routing as r on eg.searchpn between r.PN and r.NextPN
```

| SEARCHPN | PN | NEXTPN | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51235 | 51000 | 52000 | Bob |
| 1050 | 1000 | 1100 | overlap 1 |
| 1050 | 1010 | 1110 | overlap 2 |

[2nd DB2 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GoDZQ5-0)

& [matching TSQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m1nUjLYG)